# Message Vs Email

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, message

I am making an app where users can record a sound file. Once they have recorded it I would like to save it locally on the user phone. I have the sound file saved in the apps document directory. What I want to do is let the user share that file through email / text message. Ideally i would like to save it to their photo album and say hey, the file is there now go share however you want.

Now heres my question. I know how to send an email with file attachment in iOS but can I send a message? I know text messages are not allowed but look at this screenshot I took using apple's built in Voice Memos app. What is "Message" here? Do us developers have access to it?

I am trying to figure out if there are any other ways of sharing an audio file other than integrating my app with facebook/twitter/etc which I really don't want to do.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's SMS or iMessage. And you **can** send an SMS and iMessage from within your app (or at least present the user an interface which allows him to do so): google `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I readup on this topic and seems like I cannot send a sound file using SMS/iMessage i.e. MFMessageComposeViewController? Is that right?

Comment: @SamBudda any luck? I don't think you can as I stated in my answer :(

Comment: Yup, you were right. Marked your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, you cannot attach anything to an SMS or iMessage. You may only set the recipient and the "body" of the message. Believe me, I've tried to attach an image all kinds of ways.

As for other ways to share said sound file, I guess the best way is to upload the file then send the recipient a URL via text message that directs them to this particular sound file.